# Where can I find examples of a great "cold call" email for freelancing?

Tags: attracting-clients, marketing

I want to generate business through emailing, but I don't have an idea on an appropriate "cold" email. I'm targeting businesses in my local area and I want to build awareness.

Does anyone have a good link that has a good "cold" email, or do you have an template that has worked well for you?

Comment: You mean spamming everybody, not another one :( Maybe a bit harsh, possibly spear fishing is more like it.

Comment: I drafted a cold 'call' email template in this blog post (below), as well as the process for tailoring the email to the person you're contacting, so it doesn't come across as spammy: [How to build client relationships from scratch part 2: Overcoming the cold call](http://rlwinks.com/client-relationships-cold-call/)

Answer (score 8):

By definition an effective "cold calling" (cold emailing?) email should be tailor made and not from a template. Even more so if you are targeting local business.

In my opinion, creating awareness and cold calling are two different things. You can start an awareness campaign and follow it up with cold calling (which would seem the logical order).

If you need the template because of layout (although I assumed you were after content), have look at Mailchimp. They offer some great templates and tips on making an effective campaign.

Answer (score 2):

Cold calling and cold mailing are both rather sub-par ways to get clients. Ideally you first prove yourself in your niche/market/area so that people have heard of you and then they approach you and not vice versa.

The only appropriate way to get clients vs the cold approach is to warm up by doing some research and crafting a tailor-made offer specifically for the needs of the given potential client.

You take a closer look at their site, store or product and offer the exact thing they are obviously lacking. Something like "I've noticed that your site is slower than 70% of your competitors. I could do x, y, z to improve it drastically."